# App Crashes when trying to load action bar in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am quite new to Android and have been learning it myself with some help with online videos. I am attempting to use two activities to go back and forth using an action bar. The first activity is just the main activity however the second is a map activity. When running through the emulator is crashes when I press on the button to go from the first activity to the second.

Here is my code -

> Main Activity

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //declare list view
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        //create array list called places using strings
        final ArrayList<String> places = new ArrayList<>();

        places.add("Add a new location");
        //create array adapter
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,places);
        //set up list view to use array adapter
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        [![listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {][1]][1]

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);

                i.putExtra("locationInfo",position);
                //start activity with intent of i
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
```

> Map Activity -

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Intent i = getIntent();

        Log.i("LocationInfo", Integer.toString(i.getIntExtra("locationInfo", -1)));

    }
```

It seems to be crashing on the line - `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnables(true);`

I have imported the action bar library and changed the API level on my emulator to see if that was the problem. However I have got a little stuck on what the problem is with my limited experience with Android.

Any ideas on how to rectify the problem would be fantastic.

Log Cat-

[image: Log]

XML for main activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.lennydegriffa.memorableplaces.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

XML for Map Activity

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.lennydegriffa.memorableplaces.MapsActivity" />
```

Comment: Add logcat please

Comment: Please add the logcat

Comment: Specify the application theme and also add activity layout xmls(layout.activity_main and layout.activity_maps).

Comment: May we know, What does your MapActivity extends?

Comment: If you are inheriting from `ActionBarActivity`, make sure that you are calling `getSupportActionBar()`, not `getActionBar()`

Comment: Hi I have now included the log cat as a screenshot and the map activity extends fragment activity. And for the getActionBar() I am just using the library (import android.app.ActionBar;) I am not inheriting from ActionBarActivity.

Comment: Monish Kamble, the application theme I am using is AppTheme which I believe is a default one. I will add the xml for you now to have a look at.

Comment: I have finished adding the xml for the activities too, I am quite new to android so I am still learning, I do apologise for not including the other information.

Comment: Which `Activity` are your activity classes derived from? Do you import something like `android.support.v7.app...` or `android.support.v4.app...`? Maybe you have to use `getSupportActionBar();`...

Comment: Hi gus I haven't used the getSupportActionBar() class.

Comment: The only things I have imported is import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity; and import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Intent;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `ActionBarActivity or AppCompatActivity class instead of FragmentActivity` in Map Activity to have an action bar. My suggestion would be go for `AppCompatActivity`. 
**Reason behind is -** 
If you look at [ActionBarActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) or [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) then they implement  ActionBarDrawerToggle.DelegateProvider while [FragmentActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) does not implement it.

 Why I suggested `AppCompatActivity` because `ActionBarActivity` is **deprecated.**

Also If are you using support v4 library Action bar then I would suggest use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`

Comment: Hi Thanks I will give that a go.

Comment: @MrWeiser please check answer now I updated it with reason behind it

Answer (score 0):

Just check your style.xml, because it may be that you have done

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

change above to

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```